# How to calculate the deviation from a mean per subgroup in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a dataset im currently working on, I try to calculate the deviation of 'Total' for each row, depending on each subgroup in the following dataframe:

[image]

So my goal is to, for instance, calculate the deviation of 'Total' for each 'A' in the column 'Branch' for the mean of this group of 'A's, and this for every possible subgroup in the data.

Every column consists of several groups, and I calculate the mean per group in each column with the following code:

```py
for item in df.columns:
    print(df.groupby(item)['Total'].mean())
```

Which neatly returns the mean for each distinct group as a series. The last step required for my goal is to calculate for each column the 'Total' value minus this mean for each group, but I don't know how to go about this. Please notify me if what I ask is unclear.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299519/dataframe-subtract-group-wise-means. I think you are looking for `groupby` + `transform('mean')`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks ALollz!

Answer (score 1):

Like this if you are interested in standard deviation

```
df.groupby('Branch')['Total'].std()
```

But I'm not sure if that's what you're asking about.

Comment: This would give me the std at the group level, but I need it at the row level. Thanks though!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Do you want the value of the standard deviation for the respective group in a separate column? Or do you just want a column with group-mean-value?